# Which type of regex used by NMAP?

Tags: regex, nmap

Trying to scan in Robtex database with Nmap:

```
nmap --script http-robtex-reverse-ip <target>
```

But since Robtex has updated his website, the Nmap script is not working any more.

New Robtex html structure is like this:

```
    <div class="xsha">
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>
                    <span id="sharedn.b446331/_ma">Pointing to this IP number</span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <ol class="xbul">
                <li>domain1</li>
<li>domain2</li>
<li>domain3</li>
<li>domain...</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have changed my Nmap script but it not working.

```
function parse_robtex_response(data)
  local data = data:match("<span id=\"sharedn\">.-<ol.->(.-)</ol>")
  local result = {}
  if data then
    for domain in data:gmatch("<li[^>]*>(.-)</li>") do
      domain = domain:gsub("<[^>]+>","")
      table.insert(result, domain)
    end
  end
  return result
end

prerule = function() return stdnse.get_script_args("http-robtex-reverse-ip.host") ~= nil end

action = function(host, port)

  local target = stdnse.get_script_args("http-robtex-reverse-ip.host")
  local ip = ipOps.ip_to_str(target)
  if ( not(ip) or #ip ~= 4 ) then
    return stdnse.format_output(false, "The argument \"http-robtex-reverse-ip.host\" did not contain a valid IPv4 address")
  end

  local link = "/ip-lookup/"..target..""
  local htmldata = http.get("www.robtex.com", 443, link, {any_af=true})
  local domains = parse_robtex_response(htmldata.body)
  if ( #domains > 0 ) then
    return stdnse.format_output(true, domains)
  end
end
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: "it not working" is pretty vague...

Comment: do not obtain domain names

Comment: This "regex" looks like Lua patterns that are not regular expressions. Try replacing the `local data` pattern with `<span id=\"sharedn[^\"]*\">.-<ol.->(.-)</ol>` pattern. However, you have no text inside `li` tag now.

Comment: Thanks it work now fine!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably break again next time we change the webpage. Instead of scraping our site, it would be better to use the quite new free API ( https://www.robtex.com/api/ ).
It is safer, faster, and easier to parse.